# Entity Framework Core Where All

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I can do this fine in `EF.Net`, but not in `EFCore`

```
List<string> keyList = string.IsNullOrEmpty(keywords) ? new List<string>() : keywords.Split(' ').ToList();

collections = await db.ProductCollections
    .Where(m => m.Children.Count == 0 && (!keyList.Any() ? true : keyList.All(x => m.Name.Contains(x))))
    .ToListAsync();
```

I changed it into:

```
collections = await db.ProductCollections
    .Where(m => m.Children.Count == 0 && (keyList.Count == 0 || keyList.All(x => m.Name.Contains(x))))
    .ToListAsync();
```

So I guess the problem is in `keyList.All()`. How can I achieve this in EFCore?

The error message:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(p => DbSet()
> .Where(p0 => EF.Property<Nullable>(p, "ID") != null && object.Equals(
> objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable>(p, "ID"),
> objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable>(p0, "ParentId")))
> .Count() == 0 && False || __keyList_0
> .All(x => p.Name.Contains(x)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
> to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: How you know that it is not working in EF Core?

Comment: In EF6 it will have done that query in C#, not SQL, so it would have been very inefficient because it would load the entire table into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach to build query based on key list, before executing it.

```
var keys = string.IsNullOrEmpty(keywords) ? Array.Empty<string>() : keywords.Split(' ');

var query = db.ProductCollections.Where(p => p.Children.Any() == false);
foreach (var key in keys)
{
     query = query.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(key));
}

var collections = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Always prefer `Array.Empty<T>()` instead of `new T[] {}` or `new T[0]` as it avoids heap allocations.

Comment: Still hit the exception: `The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ProductCollection>()
    .Where(p => DbSet<ProductCollection>()
        .Where(p0 => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(p, "ID") != null && object.Equals(
            objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(p, "ID"), 
            objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(p0, "ParentId")))
        .Any() == False)
    .Where(p => __keys_0
        .All(key => p.Name.Contains(key)))' could not be translated...`

Comment: @AlvinStefanus, please check updated version(copy-paste issue), where instead of using `All` method, we create query for all keys.

Comment: Its fine now, its so inconvenient though. Thanks

Comment: @AlvinStefanus, it depends :), I found it more convenient for reader, because reader don't need to dive into multiple embedded expressions to understand the logic.