EF Core get all entities that have all childrens in array
I'm making a search system and I want to use EF Core to get a list of all entries that have all tags contained in an array.
I tried to use this code but I get an Expression could not be translated exception.
var query = dbContext.JobOffers
    .Include(o => o.Tags)
    .Where(o => dbTags.All(t => o.Tags.Any(m => m.Value == t.Value))) // Can't be translated
    .Where(o => dbContext.Levenshtein(o.Title, filters.Query) <= 10);

// ...

var dbOffers = await query.ToListAsync(); // Throws exception

I want to fetch all entries that have all tags contained in dbTags.

Have you already checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65557753/entity-framework-core-where-all the question is not exactly the same with yours but It may help to re-write (change logic) your code
